# Would bolting four 3" square tubes to an existing 3" square tube (one per side) increase rigidity?

Tags: structural-beam

I had a pier fabricated for my telescope consisting of a 1/4" steel plate, 10" diameter, bolted to a concrete pad.  A 3" by 34" square steel tube is welded to the base plate and the mount head is welded to the tube. The mount head consists of two 1/4" steel plates, 8" diameter, separated by three 2" square tubes, 6" long.   I have since added an equatorial wedge to the top of the mount.  This wedge converts the telescope mount to an equatorial mount.  But it added another 12" to the height of the telescope.  The telescope assembly that sits on top of the pier weighs about 70 lbs.

The Problem:
There is a noticeable wobble when the scope is disturbed - BAD FOR ASTROPHOTOGRAPHY.

Further research (yes, I wish I found this before I had the pier fabricated) says I should have used a "thick" base plate and a 1/4" steel tube 8" in diameter. https://www.cloudynights.com/articles/cat/articles/how-to/pier-design-fundamentals-r1236

What to do:
I can start over but I have already invested into the existing pier.  So I am looking for ways to increase the rigidity of the original 3" pier post.  That's where my question comes in:  Would bolting four 3" square tubes to an existing 3" square tube (one per side) increase rigidity? I am considering bolting vs welding because the extra tubes would sit over the bolts that mount the whole pier to the concrete base.  If I weld them I can no longer remove the pier, if needed.

I would appreciate any advice you may have.  Below is an image of the original design and a photograph of the current setup
:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear.. other than starting from scratch, I am basically looking for ideas to "beef up" the existing pier to minimize the wobble it has.  While the existing pier can support the weight it wobbles when a small force is applied to the telescope (like an upside down pendulum).

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing seems very 'top heavy'.  It may be in danger of falling over.

You could lean heavy concrete blocks onto the main vertical post (about half way up) from all sides, but perhaps cables as shown below would be better if you can find suitable solid points of attachment.

[image]

The three 2x6 posts seem a good place, then go horizontally A,B,C or to the ground D,E,F.  You would need to get them very tight.

All the best with it.

Comment: Don't you think those cables would be serious impediments to using the telescope?

Comment: @ D. Halsey  impediments, yes, but not necessarily serious, the OP would probably get used to them being there.  They could be removed if set up right when the telescope wasn't in use.  Or maybe wooden poles, cut just the right length and jammed in place similar to the green cables, they might be easier to take away.  If starting from scratch a different design would be better, but the OP has already made it

Comment: I have thought of something similar to the cables but I'm afraid, even knowing they are there, I would stumble over them in the dark.

Comment: @ Mike S ok, then perhaps the concrete block idea mentioned in the comments above.  Apart from that there's no other suggestions unfortunately, unless others have some.  All the best with it.